# Combinations of divisors

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, combinations

How to count multiplicity the number of combinations of divisors of $n$ if the number of proper divisors of $n$ is $2p-1$? Note that $n$ is a perfect number.

I did tried combinations, since the number of elements is $2p-1$, so the number of combinations will be using the sum of divisors from combinations.

Since we need to exclude empty combinations, we subtracted $1$. But I got so confused about the reason why it was done that way.

Comment: What's the question?  What does "multiplicity the number of combinations of divisors of $n$" mean?

Comment: Maybe if you wrote out an explicit example it would clarify things.  $n=6$ is a perfect number.  What are you asking for $n=6$?

Comment: Can you clarify your question?  As it stands it isn't at all clear what you are asking (at least, it isn't at all clear to me). Can you write out the case of $n=6$?

Comment: Voting to close the question as it is unclear what you are asking.  If you can, please edit your post for clarity.  Note:  Examples are often the best way to illustrate a question.

Comment: You've posted this question [twice](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2931701/counting-multiplicity-for-total-number-of-combinations-of-divisors).  The first time didn't get any responses either.  I expect that's because nobody can figure out what you are asking.  Please, don't simply repost the question.  Make an effort to clarify what you are asking.  Like I keep saying, works some explicit examples.  the first two examples, $6,28$, should be very easy to work with.  do the computation for them so we can tell what it is you are trying to compute.